# The path to the driver executable must be set

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HomeController {

    private final ParseData parseArsenkin;


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome(){
        return "home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String postHome(){
        parseArsenkin.parse();
        return "result";
    }
}
```

**WebDriverConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverConfig {

    @Bean
    public FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver() {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        return new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

**ParseData.java**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParseData {
    private final FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver;
    public void parse() {
        String baseUrl = "http://google.com";
        firefoxDriver.get(baseUrl);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [/home/michael/Documents/JavaProjects/positions/target/classes/ru/pcask/positions/controller/HomeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parseArsenkin' defined in file [/home/michael/Documents/JavaProjects/positions/target/classes/ru/pcask/positions/service/ParseArsenkin.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firefoxDriver' defined in class path resource [ru/pcask/positions/configuration/WebDriverConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver]: Factory method 'firefoxDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-selenium-webdriver-path-error#automated-setup

According to the tutorial I don't have to provide geckodriver manually.

What have I done wrongly?

Comment: do you need a webscrapping tool? https://medium.com/@sushain_Dilishan/building-web-scraping-api-with-spring-boot-jsoup-a0cc19dbd5dd

Answer (score -2):

add in WebDriverConfig  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","src/main/resources/geckodriver.exe" );